# Meteor's Accounts.onEmailVerificationLink with React and React Router

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, react-router, meteor-accounts

I'm trying to get email verification to work with React/Meteor using Meteor's accounts-password package. I'm using React Router. I'm not sure where to put/how to call this:

```
Accounts.onEmailVerificationLink(function(token, done) {
 Accounts.verifyEmail(token);
});
```

I have a sign-up component and container, and I'm trying to get the verification email to link to the sign-in component/container and verify. I've done the following in a Meteor.(isServer) Meteor.startup block:

```
Accounts.urls.verifyEmail = function(){
 return Meteor.absoluteUrl("restaurantsignin");
};
```

My react router file looks like this:

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/restaurantsignin" component={RestaurantSignInContainer} />
        <Route path="/restaurantsignup" component={RestaurantSignUpContainer} />
        <Route path="/customersignup" component={CustomerSignUpContainer} />
        <Route path="/restaurantresetemail" component={RestaurantResetEmailContainer} />
        <Route path="/restaurantresetpassword" component={RestaurantResetPasswordContainer} />

        <Route path="/restaurant/:restaurantName" component={MenuPage} />
      </Route>
    </Router>, document.getElementById('app')
  );

});
```

My react component file looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Radium from 'radium';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Alert, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class RestaurantSignIn extends React.Component {

  handleAlertVerifiedDismiss() {
    document.getElementById('alert_verified_box').style.display = 'none';
  }

  render() {
    var styles = {
.
.
.
  return (
    <div style={styles.signInContainer}>
. 
.
.
and so on
```

The email verification link is being sent successfully and is redirecting to the /restaurantsignin link correctly. I'm just not sure how to properly verify the user once they reach the sign in page -- I'd like to have them verified before they sign in (as soon as they click the link)-- the meteor docs say to use the above Accounts code snippet but beyond that, I haven't found anything online. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 3):

`Accounts.urls.verifyEmail` function takes in a token parameter, so you can do the following:

```
Accounts.urls.verifyEmail = function(token) {
  return Meteor.absoluteUrl("restaurantsignin?token="+token)
}
```

Then the user clicks on the link in the email the token is already in the query param which you can extract with `this.props.location.query.token`. So in your `RestaurantSignIn` component's `componentWillMount` you can call:

```
Accounts.verifyEmail(this.props.location.query.token, function(error) {...})
```

If there are no errors you can navigate directly to an authenticated route with `this.props.history.replace('/dashboard')` because `Accounts.verifEmail()` automatically logs the user in.

Comment: Thanks! it works.. I uses `browserHistory.push` instead of `this.props.history.replace`

Comment: Where to place this code "Accounts.urls.verifyEmail = function(token) {
  return Meteor.absoluteUrl("restaurantsignin?token="+token)
}"? Maybe in "Meteor.startup()"?